# Learning assembler with no programming experience

Tags: assembly, mips, powerpc

I have no programming experience except the most basic ability to read some ASM operands (MIPS).

Due to a serious medical condition, I have the luxury of having 1 year of free time. I cannot work or go out much during this time so I've decided I want to learn ASM.

I am interested in hacking games; specifically GameCube (PowerPC ASM) and PlayStation (MIPS ASM).

What is the best way for someone like me to learn ASM properly?

I want to be fluent enough that I can write simple programs and it is important that I can really understand it, so I can view game's functions in a disassembler (using breakpoints and such).

I will essentially need to reverse engineer small amounts of the game that take my interest so I can hack/change/modify certain properties (completely legal of course).

This is just a hobby for me. I have no interest in getting a job in this field; my university major is completely unrelated to programming, and I can't take programming courses at my university.

Comment: A good book will set you forward. To reverse-engineer programs w/o source, you need a good debugger or several (and you need to learn to use code & data breakpoints and single-stepping), a good disassembler or several, and a lot of patience. Anyway, to do any non-trivial changes in the code, you need to learn well the assembly in question. First learn your preferred asm, then start hacking with a really small executable to learn with. In big ones the problem is how to find the right instruction[s] within thousands of lines of code. Back in DOS, Gametools (G3X) had an excellent memory scanner.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand things at a deeper level, then I suggest that you look at a course like Udacity's [An Introduction to Computer Science](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101) which teaches the rudiments of computer programming using python.

Then I'd go on and look at some intermediate programming courses - such as theory of data structures - this sounds really boring - but if you don't get the fundamentals in a high level language you'll be completely lost in assembly when you have to manage *everything* yourself! Only then would I look at game assembler - which will be typically much more advanced than "hello world"!

I suggest that you don't jump to assembly too early :-)

I'm not hung up on Udacity - but a GPU programming course has just started - though it is definitely an advanced course!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand MIPS assembler you should get a copy of [See MIPS Run](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120884216). This book assumes you have a reasonable knowledge of the C language. If you are not familiar with C, there are many books available.  [Programming in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326663) by Stephen G. Kochan is the first useful looking on I found on Amazon, though I've never read it.

(You might find learning Python to be a bit of a side-track if your goal is to understand how a particular game works.)

Answer (score 0):

To learn MIPS, I use [MIPSIT](http://www.bostream.nu/mats.brorsson/mipsit/) that'll depend on your environment. You can get an actual chip or simulate / emulate.